# Python MySQLdb- using multiple database tables in query

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python

I am writing a script in Python and I am using `MySQLdb` package.

```
 con1 = mdb.connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'teacher') 
 con2 = mdb.connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'student', true)
```

I can execute a query using a single cursor in python. But I want to write query to use tables from both the database at once. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Was looking for an answer to the same question. Found that connecting without specifying the database will allow you to query multiple tables:

```
db = _mysql.connect('localhost', 'user', 'password')
```

Then you can query different tables from different databases:

```
select table1.field1,
       table2.field2
from database1.table1 inner join
     database2.table2 on database2.table2.join_field = database1.field1.join_field
```

And boom goes the dynamite

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PyMySQL and you are trying to create a query using multiple databases:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(
    host = "your_host",
    user = "your_user",
    password = "your_password",
    database = None,
    cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
)
```

The difference will be to pass the *database* variable as *None*